# PowerShell + C# Elevate-Privileges Function Explained

Tags: c#, powershell

Can anyone explain what this function written in PowerShell/C# is doing or why it's required? I use it take ownership of things programatically but would like to know what the C# code is doing.

```
function Elevate-Privileges {
param($Privilege)
$Definition = @"
using System;
using System.Runtime.InteropServices;

public class AdjPriv {
    [DllImport("advapi32.dll", ExactSpelling = true, SetLastError = true)]
        internal static extern bool AdjustTokenPrivileges(IntPtr htok, bool disall, ref TokPriv1Luid newst, int len, IntPtr prev, IntPtr rele);

    [DllImport("advapi32.dll", ExactSpelling = true, SetLastError = true)]
        internal static extern bool OpenProcessToken(IntPtr h, int acc, ref IntPtr phtok);

    [DllImport("advapi32.dll", SetLastError = true)]
        internal static extern bool LookupPrivilegeValue(string host, string name, ref long pluid);

    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack = 1)]
        internal struct TokPriv1Luid {
            public int Count;
            public long Luid;
            public int Attr;
        }

    internal const int SE_PRIVILEGE_ENABLED = 0x00000002;
    internal const int TOKEN_QUERY = 0x00000008;
    internal const int TOKEN_ADJUST_PRIVILEGES = 0x00000020;

    public static bool EnablePrivilege(long processHandle, string privilege) {
        bool retVal;
        TokPriv1Luid tp;
        IntPtr hproc = new IntPtr(processHandle);
        IntPtr htok = IntPtr.Zero;
        retVal = OpenProcessToken(hproc, TOKEN_ADJUST_PRIVILEGES | TOKEN_QUERY, ref htok);
        tp.Count = 1;
        tp.Luid = 0;
        tp.Attr = SE_PRIVILEGE_ENABLED;
        retVal = LookupPrivilegeValue(null, privilege, ref tp.Luid);
        retVal = AdjustTokenPrivileges(htok, false, ref tp, 0, IntPtr.Zero, IntPtr.Zero);
        return retVal;
    }
}
"@
    $ProcessHandle = (Get-Process -id $pid).Handle
    $type = Add-Type $definition -PassThru
    $type[0]::EnablePrivilege($processHandle, $Privilege)
}
```

Comment: The function enables a [privilege](https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/windows/desktop/aa379306). Even a user logged on as an administrator will, by default, not have privileges enabled for certain operations that affect system-wide resources (like messing with the security event log, or changing the system time), and they must be enabled explicitly (and usually on a temporary basis). The function shown here doesn't mention any privileges itself; it can be used to enable any privilege by name (like the `SeTakeOwnershipPrivilege` you use to bypass security).

Comment: Note that, for files specifically, you're better off delegating to the `takeown` command than reinventing the wheel. You'd only need to mess with the ownership privilege if you wanted to adjust the security of something that's not a file, but then you'd need even *more* P/Invoking -- it's not something you'd typically do in PowerShell, in any case.

Comment: There are other functions in the PowerShell module for taking ownership of Files, folders and registry keys. They all use this function though so I was curious what exactly this is doing. The full script is linked here: https://github.com/W4RH4WK/Debloat-Windows-10/blob/master/lib/take-own.psm1

I use this module to take ownership of some of the Windows 10 default packages and then remove them through DISM. It's the only way to get rid of that Mixed Reality Portal in the start menu.